# Sorting by multiple fields (collation)

Tags: objectbox

In my objectbox model class I have 2 fields:

```
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class, dbType = String.class)
public LocalDateTime dateModified;
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class, dbType = String.class)
public LocalDateTime dateTaken;
```

Some elements have both fields filled while other have dateModified not null and dateTaken is null. I'd like to sort query results by dateTaken if it's not null, otherwise by dateModified. Is it possible to do so with Objectbox query (i.e. some sort of collation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind doing this on the Java/Kotlin side of things, you can do this using `QueryBuilder.sort(comparator)`.

Since you implement the comparator, you sort by whatever you please. Pseudo code example:

```
dateThis = x.date1 != null? x.date1: x.data2
dateOther = y.date1 != null? y.date1: y.data2
return dateThis.compareTo(dateOther)
```

Comment: Thank you Markus! Great solution.

Comment: Happy to help! And since this is your first question here: please consider accepting and up-voting the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Dear Markus! I wanted to up-vote your answer but unfortunately my reputation does not allow it. I'm very sorry about it. :(